# Какой паттерн проектирования применим для передачи данных из одного класса в другой?

Tags: php, ооп

Задано 2 класса:

1. ProductsList
2. FilterRender

Первый класс получает список товаров из БД и формирует массив характеристик со значениями для фильтра.

Класс `FilterRender` должен получить список этих характеристик и построить фильтр.

Я делаю таким образом:

```
$productList = (new ProductsList())->getList();
$filterRender = new FilterRender($productList->getProperties());
$filterRender->run();
```

Т.е. список характеристик передаю просто через конструктор.
Далее, если пользователь применил какой-то фильтр на сайте, соответственно список товаров на странице отфильтруется, и появится новый список характеристик для рендера фильтра, и мне придется проделать тоже самое - инициализацию через конструктор и т.д.

Есть ли возможность, применить какой-то паттерн проектирования, чтобы `FilterRender` подписался на события появления нового списка характеристик, а если получил список характеристик, то сам же вызывает у себя метод `run()`.

Насколько это правильно с точки зрения проектирования? И как это делается?

Comment: Ну, у вас практически реализация Prototype паттерна, что не устраивает? Можно, например, в конструкторе вызывать `getList()`? сделать аля "флажок". В конструкторе класса ProductsList: `... __construct ($list = false) {...` и в теле конструктора проверять если `list === true` то вызывать `getList()` ; или же сделать аналогично но по именам функций, и надо будет просто в конструктор передать имя функции или что-то, что сами укажете.

Comment: вы же понимаете, что когда пользователь что-то изменил на сайте это будет уже новый запрос к серверу и вы все равно потащите все это заново с базы и т.п. ? время жизни скрипта ограничено одним запросом, все эти объекты не висят в памяти, пока пользователь сидит на сайте.